# My rails simple form is not responding correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

I have a little bit of a problem with a website, I have an index page, which is designed to have posts which people can rate with a slider. Problem right now is that rails is not recognizing what I want to do wiht this error code
[image]

Here is what my form looks like

```
    <%= simple_form_for [@post, @rating ] do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :rating, as: :range, min: 1, max: 100 %>
        <%= f.submit "Submittt"%>
    <% end %>
```

I have added the "@rating = Rating.new" line in my posts controller, and have also nested my "resources :ratings" inside my "resources :posts"
Even in my RatingController - create section I have added the line "@rating = rating.new(params)"
Can you tell me what is wrong?
Thank you very much!

Comment: It is the route being created inside those brackets that the form is submitting to.  The route created doesn't exist.

Comment: but i have the ratings routes nested inside the posts in routes.rb like this:
``` resources :posts do 
    resources :ratings
  end ```
should that create the route?

Comment: If you run `rake routes` is there a path called `ratings_path` somewhere?  Based on your comment I assume not, probably something more like `posts_ratings_path` or something?  The form is looking for `ratings_path` which sounds like it doesn't exist.  So fix the path the form is looking to submit to and you will be good to go.